# How do I stop graphs appearing cropped when using D3 splines?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crop, spline

Our UI uses D3 and when applying splines to smooth the data we have several cropping or out of bounds issues as follows:

Spline is cropped at top of graph
[image: Spline is cropped at top of graph]
Spline goes below x-axis
[image: Spline goes below x-axis]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think `domain` of your y-axis is wrong. It should be then `[min_of_values, max_of_values]`. Also you can try the `nice` function of d3js to make your scale nice. if you post the code with data then it will be good to debug

Comment: What's your objective: 1) prevent the interpolations from overshooting in the first place, or 2) use them as they are and adjust the clipped area to show the entire graph? Please share some code for people to better help you.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I cannot share code as I am the product owner and not the dev house. However, your points are noted and I will feedback here and credit once I have informed my internal team and the dev house of the options. Thanks.

Comment: Easy answer is to just pad the domain `y.domain([maxValue * 1.2, minValue * 1.2])`

Answer (score 0):

Use .getBoundingClientRect() on each of the set of paths to get the extreme top and bottom bounds, then adjust the axis range or the visible margins of the chart accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will feedback once we decide on the approach to be used.